# How can I order rows in excel based on a ratio through vba?

Tags: excel, vba, sorting

first time post on here so hopefully I'll give enough info to get some help.

I have a dataset in excel which contains multiple clients in column 1, I want to order it based on a ratio in blocks of 10. So for example if the ratio was 60/40 between client 1 and 2 it would need to order 6 rows client 1, 4 rows client 2, 6 rows client 1, 4 rows client 2 until the end of the data.

Is there any way I can do this, either through sorting in excel or using VBA, I've been trying for a couple of days and am stumped.

Thanks.

Comment: By ratio, you mean the number of times "client 1" appears in your list versus the number of times "client 2" appears? Are there only two clients in the list?

Comment: Yes, but I need it to be a repeatable action and the number of clients will vary

Comment: So if you can have more than two clients, isn't the ratio the number of times each client appears versus the total number of entries?

Comment: Sorry, I should have said, the ratio is a manually set variable. So the data needs to be sorted by ratio in blocks of 10, until a client runs out, then it would just be the remainder of the 2nd client (in a 2 client) situation.
Sorry if I'm not being very clear!

Comment: Is it possible to add attachments? I've got a manual example of what I mean

Comment: You can add a picture to your post or a link to a public file share

Comment: http://snag.gy/HJDqG.jpg

Comment: You should edit your original post to include the link plus the bit about the ratio being a manually set variable. I think you need to use VBA - do you have any experience?

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps. This will place your blocks in columns next to each other. I did not test this but hopefully the idea will get you somewhere.

```
Sub ClientRatios()

'DataSet is in range A:A
'Make the ratios of the Clients Add up to 10
'You can have a maximum of 10 clients

Dim Nextempty As Range
Dim j As Long
Dim i As Long

'Repeat the following idea for each client and you should get what you're looking for

'+++Client1+++

'=================================
i = Range("Clinet1_Ratio")
ClientName = Range("Clinet1_Name")
'=================================

Total = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("A:A"), ClientName)
Do While Total < 0
    j = i
    c = 2
    Do While j > 0
        If j > Total Then j = Total
        Nextempty = Cells(Cells.Rows.Count, Columns(c)).End(xlUp).Row + 1
        Nextempty = ClientName
        j = j - 1
    Loop
c = c + 1
Total = Total - i
Loop

'+++Client2+++
    'Do the same for all 10 clients

 End Sub
```

Comment: If this answer helped you achieve what you were looking for please mark it as so.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use the `Dictionary` object found in the Microsoft Scripting Runtime library (included with Windows). Links [here](http://www.snb-vba.eu/VBA_Dictionary_en.html) and [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/187234)

1. Read your source data into a `dictionary` so this stores the client names and the count of each name.
2. Loop through your ratios cells, each time writing the client names in the dictionary and then decreasing the count. If the count = 0 for a name, then do not write out that name.
3. When all client name counts in dictionary = 0, then quit the loop and you're done.